# Android preferences ClassNotFoundExceptions that's killing me

Tags: android, android-preferences

I ran across an exception that seems to appear on the emulator and personal debuggable device.

**This is the preferences.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header 
        android:title="sound"
        android:summary=""
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff"
        android:fragment="com.example.app.activities.PreferencesActivity$SoundSettingsPreferenceFragment" />
</preference-headers>
```

**This is the preferences_sound file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="First Category"
        android:key="first_category">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pref_cbx"
            android:title="checkbox"
            android:summary="checkbox summ"
            android:defaultValue="true" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**This is the relevant code Activity**:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import com.example.app.R;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preferences, target);
    }

    public static class SoundSettingsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_sound);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the output error**:

```
10-30 11:31:58.812: E/ActivityThread(9783): Failed to inflate
10-30 11:31:58.812: E/ActivityThread(9783): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class preference-headers
```

...

```
10-30 11:31:58.812: E/ActivityThread(9783): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.preference.preference-headers
```

...

Comment: we are curious. try out what is recommended and report back.

Comment: SOLUTION: 
Don't call this line on an headers .xml file:
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

Comment: I know, I know, late. But you should make this comment into an answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Usually this error shows up when you neglect to export an external lib that you're using. If you're using an external jar file, make sure to go into the properties and check off the export checkbox in that tab.

```
java build path -> order and export
```

Comment: I doubt its this issue. I think its a random issue and not something consistent.

Comment: yeah... it could be a lot of things.... it's not a very useful error, so, I'm just taking a stab at what usually causes it for me.

Comment: tell you what... I'll upvote your answer... :) welcome to 1000+

Comment: Yeah 1k feels good. Now that I think of it, its a runtime exception. A missing lib will give a compile time problem, a runtime issue can be due to order of libs. Yeah.. I think it can be what you have too. Upvote..

Comment: @Siddharth, obviously it's a runtime exception, but all the versions fit, both on emulator and device.
Hell, I even ran it in a different Eclipse :/

Comment: Yea I know. Its not about a image fitting the screen issue. Its about android and its behavior in fitting images. Android resizes images, and resizing of images is a very expensive bitmap operation. I can bet its a random issue on some random phone's. I am sure you are not able to reproduce it on emulator or the most famous phones, right ?

Comment: I'm using the default icon image, nothing more.
Stripped down everything. It's definitely something to do with the compiling, because this simple preferences project should work. ( have a Galaxy s2, Android 4)

Answer (score 2):

Android resizes its bitmaps from drawable folder to fit the screen. It does it during the inflating of layout. If you have an application that has images only in "drawable" folder (or for that matter, if you have only 1 folder for all resolutions), then the resize sometimes fails. You can even get OOM exceptions. So I suggest that you create a drawable-mdpi folder and copy all the drawables from that single folder to mdpi too.

I know it sounds crazy, but most inflating layout issues disappear with this one change. Try it. Doesn't hurt anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the **theme** that applied to the PreferenceActivity whether is compatible with the PreferenceActivity object or not.